# Django Many to Many, ordering and serializing using REST

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I was designing a system which allows users to select a number of objects (say 5) in a pre-configured ordered set of objects (count > 5). Basically, the user has to select top 5 objects in a set of 9. I have to save these entries and find out those objects which have the maximum votes (maximum selection) and a winner based on the most right entries.

My models:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    '''Info about user '''

class Contest(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)


class ObjectsForContest(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    contest = models.ManyToManyField('Contest', through='OrderedObjectsForContest')

class OrderedObjectsForContest(models.Model):
    choice = models.ForeignKey(ObjectsForContest)
    contest = models.ForeignKey(Contest, related_name='ordered_options')
    order = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['order']

class UserEntriesForContest(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="entries_for_contest")
    contest = models.ForeignKey(Contest, related_name='participating_users')
    objects_selected = models.ManyToManyField(ObjectsForContest, through='OrderedChoicesByUser', null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.unique_id

class OrderedChoicesByUser(models.Model):
    choice = models.ForeignKey(ObjectsForContest)
    contest = models.ForeignKey(UserEntriesForContest)
    order = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['order']
```

My serializers are pretty straight forward. 
Serializer:

```
class ContestObjectsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ObjectsForContest
        exclude = ("contests", )


class ContestObjectsThroughSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    choice = ContestObjectsSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = OrderedObjectsForContest
        exclude = ("id", )


class Contest(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    winner = SimpleUserProfileSerializer()  #this serializes the user and not included here.
    choices = ContestObjectsThroughSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Contest


class UserEntriesForContestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    choices_made = ContestObjectsSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = UserEntriesForContest
```

How can I find the choice that has been selected by the maximum number of users according to their order?

Ex. 
Objects according to contest: (Name, order)

```
(Apple, 1), (Orange, 2), (Grapes, 3), (Mango, 4), (Apricot, 5), (Cherry, 6), (Guava, 7), (Jackfruit, 8), (Lime, 9)
```

Let us assume that there are 5 users whose choices are:

```
#User 1:
(Apple, 1), (Lime, 2), (Grapes, 3), (Mango, 4), (Apricot, 5)
#User 2:
(Apple, 1), (Orange, 2), (Lime, 3), (Mango, 4), (Apricot, 5)
#User 3:
(Apple, 1), (Orange, 2), (Grapes, 3), (Cherry, 4), (Apricot, 5)
#User 4:
(Apple, 1), (Orange, 2), (Lime, 3), (Cherry, 4), (Apricot, 5)
#User 5:
(Apple, 1), (Lime, 2), (Grapes, 3), (Cherry, 4), (Apricot, 5)
```

The winning list should be:

```
(Apple, 1), (Orange, 2), (Grapes, 3), (Cherry, 3), (Apricot, 5)
```

I need to know how can I get this list given my models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many-to-Many Order can be done by SerializerMethodField in DRF

```
students_listss = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_students_list')

def get_students_list(self, instance):
    return Student.objects\
        .filter()\
        .order_by('name')\
        .values_list('name', flat=True)
```

you can apply order condition as usual in order_by()

Answer (score -1):

use the tastypie REST framework to get the details. by using tatsypie you can access files by using http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html#tomanyfield

Comment: My question was to find a way where I can find out the winner and the winning objects. It is not about serializing (getting) the info. 
Moreover there are no "files" involved.